# I have to configure background music and voice with ffmpeg such that whenever voice will play background music volume will be less than voice?

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -i voice1.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=enable='between(t,0,35)':volume=.5:eval=frame[bg];[1:a]atrim=end=50[voice]" -map "[bg]" -map "[voice]" -ac 2 output.mp3`

\I tried to configure this command this didn't work anything else if possible please let me know

background music should be with lower volume when voice are playing other than that music should play normally.